# Scroll to a certain height slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im doing this to scroll to a certain position:

```
window.scrollTo(0, scrollPos);
```

But it jumps up immediately. How do I make it scroll slowly?

I tried:

```
$('body').animate({
  scrollTo: scrollPos,
 }, 1500);
```

but still jumps up

Answer (score 1):

The property you want is `scrollTop`

```
$('body').animate({
  scrollTop: scrollPos,
 }, 1500);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/seancannon/SELJZ/

Comment: also, use 'html, body' as a selector instead of just 'body' or firefox might get annoying